# Why do nil ideals annihilate simple modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

A nil ideal $N$ of a ring $R$ is defined as follows:

$(N,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$

$\forall x \in N, \forall r \in R :\quad x \cdot r \in N$

$\forall x \in N, \forall r \in R : \quad r \cdot x \in N$

$\forall x \in N, \exists n\in \mathbb{Z}: x^n=0$

For any element $a\in R$ and $e\in N$, $ae$ is nilpotent: $(ae)^n=a^ne^n=a^n.0=0$

Hence, $eR$ is a nilpotent ideal and hence a nil ideal. My book says that hence, it is a subset of the Jacobson radical (the set of elements which annihilate simple $R$-modules), but I can't really see how that follows.

NOTE: $R$ is assumed to be Artinian, in this case (i.e. it satisfies the descending chain condition on ideals)

Comment: Your definition of $N $ is unclear to me. Why does it refer to $N $ inside?

Comment: As it's an ideal, the product of any element in $N$ with any element in $R$ must be in $N$.

Comment: The definition still does not make sense. You cannot use $N $ when defining $N $.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected the definition

Comment: Ouch. You are defining (by axioms) what it means to be **a** nil ideal, not what **the** nil ideal is. There is no such thing as **the** nil ideal of a ring.

Comment: Ok, is the definition alright now?

Comment: Yes, it is. (As far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the $R$-module $M$ is simple then for $a \in R$ we have $aM=0$ or $aM=M$. suppose $aM \ne 0$ then $aM=M$. if $a \ne 0$ is nilpotent, then $\exists n \gt 1$ such that $a^n=0$. then 
$$
a^nM=0
$$
this requires 
$$
a(a^{n-1}M) =0
$$
but now $a^{n-1}M=M \Rightarrow aM=0 \Rightarrow a^{n-1}M=0$, a contradiction.

so $a^{n-1}M=0$. if $n-1 \gt 1$ we may repeat the argument until we arrive at $a^1M =0$

Comment: This elementary approach is the best imo, but unfortunately it's not clear how the centrality of $a$ was used. In general, one can have a simple left module such that $aM$ is neither zero nor $M$.

Comment: So what's the condition on $a$? That it belongs to the centre?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt in the original question you mentioned $ar=ra$ for all $r$ (my notation slightly different)

Comment: Yes, I then corrected the definition according to the definition on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory), which doesn't require the elements of the ideal to be central (I'm not sure where I got the idea that they should be)

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt We generally frown upon changing the wording of a post in such a way as to make answers inapplicable. You don't know where you got the idea? That isn't very believable. What sources were you working from?

Comment: The user @Darij Grinberg suggested I change the definition because I had used $N$ to define $N$, so I changed it to wikipedia's definition of an ideal and added the condition that every element is nilpotent.

Comment: That was just what I remembered reading in my book (Introduction to Ring Theory, Paul Cohn). However, I've just checked, and there is no mention that the elements in the ideal must be central. It was just my memory faulting me, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt I understand where darij was coming from, and why you made the later edits, but I just wanted to alert you to the community standard. It's OK this time, but if you did it a few more times you'd draw negative attention :)

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt If $a$ is a central nilpotent, then that makes $aR$ a nilpotent ideal, so it's not a totally unnatural condition for your situation...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your understanding and patience

Answer (score 1):

The nilideal is contained in the nilradical, since $1-ax$ is a unit whenever $x$ is nilpotent. The nilradical is the intersection of all the kernels of irreducible representations.

Comment: Why does $x$ being nilpotent imply that $1-ax$ has an inverse? I need to show there exists an $i\in R$ such that $(1-ax)i=i-axi=1$.

Comment: Nevermind, got it :)

Comment: $x$ being nilpotent does not imply that $1-ax$ has an inverse. However, if $x \in N$, then $ax \in N$ as well (since $N$ is an ideal), and thus $ax$ is nilpotent, which shows that $1-ax$ has an inverse.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Since $a$ and $x$ commute, it does.

Comment: Oh! The current version of the OP no longer requires $a$ and $x$ to commute.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'd be rather silly to define the nilideal of a ring that's not commutative, mainly because it is not always an ideal. It is a $Z(A)$-module, though.

Comment: Yes, which is why there is no "the nilideal" but only "a nil ideal". The OP has been fixed now.

Comment: @darijgrinberg ok, so if there is an $n$ such that $(ax)^n=0$ then $(1-ax)(1+ax+(ax)^2+...+(ax)^{n-1})=1-(ax)^n=1$, so $1-ax$ has an inverse.

Comment: As this solution doesn't use the centrality of $a$ (as far as I can tell), should I accept this one instead?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt It does, since you're using that $(ax)^n =a^nx^n$.